# Why does vwd.webinfo always get automatically checked out from source control?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2008, vs-web-site-project, vcs-checkout

We have a 2008 solution that has a file system website as part of the solution. This solution is under source control with Team Foundation Server. Every time the solution is closed it either checks out a file called vwd.webinfo or attempts to and complains that someone else already has it checked out.

Removing the file from source control does not fix the issue because it gets re-added automatically for some reason.

Why does this happen and is there something we can do about it to remove this nag?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. open "source control explorer"
2. find vwd.webinfo in the correct path
3. click "delete"
4. chek-in the operation to solve this problem

The file will still be in your file system and solution, but not under source-control. You won't see "plus" or "v" or "lock" button

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAVee.png]

Comment: You can also avoid this problem by checking the file in the pending changes when you first add the solution to source control and then press undo pending changes. This way the file is not checked in to TFS in the first place. But would be nice if Microsoft just never tried to add it to TFS in the first place.

Comment: This doesn't work entirely for me.  The file does get removed from TFS, but my next pending checkin just wants to add it again.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Property Pages, select Build on the left, and uncheck "Build Web site as part of solution" Then you can delete the file and it won't get created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to delete this file manually and have it not reappear. This file holds some information that used to be located elsewhere in the project in earlier versions but apparently is not necessary. Close your solution before deleting the file from source control and on the disk.